# .NET socket webserver HTTP POST request body

Tags: c#, http, sockets, embedded

I am doing an embedded project in C# and I have written a socket based web server. Everything works well, except I can't for the life of me get the request body. Content-Length says that there is 12 characters, but the socket.Recieve method only gets the headers.

```
while (true)
{

    using (Socket clientSocket = listeningSocket.Accept())
    {
        IPEndPoint clientIP = clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
        Debug.Print("Received request from " + clientIP.ToString());
        var x = clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint;

        int availableBytes = clientSocket.Available;

        Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + availableBytes.ToString() + " request bytes available");

        int bytesReceived = (availableBytes > maxRequestSize ? maxRequestSize : availableBytes);
        if (bytesReceived > 0)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesReceived]; // Buffer probably should be larger than this.
            int readByteCount = clientSocket.Receive(buffer, bytesReceived, SocketFlags.None);

            using (Request r = new Request(clientSocket, Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(buffer)))
            {
                Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + r.URL);
                if (requestReceived != null) requestReceived(r);

            }


        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

`availableBytes` = 499

`bytesReceived` = 499

`readByteCount` = 487 (12 characters short)

What am I missing here? The body is multipart form data if that makes any difference.

Comment: Just in terms of investigation, do you get a different readByteCount if you use SocketFlags.Peek ?

Comment: @Russ I've tried all socket flags. No Luck.

Comment: You might want to use my embeddable web server: http://webserver.codeplex.com. It's free and is coded in C#

Comment: @jgauffin does that work on .net micro framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int bytesReceived = (availableBytes > maxRequestSize ? maxRequestSize : availableBytes);
```

If `maxRequestSize` is 487, then you will get the results you describe.

Also remember `Content-Length` is not bytes - it's octets: [What's the "Content-Length" field in HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773396/whats-the-content-length-field-in-http-header) (OK I'm being pedantic - and octet is 8 bits ;))

Comment: MaxRequestSize is 1000, I know what you are saying about the length...but the bytes aren't coming in...

Comment: Why are you using the OutOfBand flag, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how reliable that `Available` property is. It looks like it's only useful for non-blocking sockets, and then only as a boolean flag saying that *something* is available.

Why not just read the stream in a loop parsing messages as you go?

Comment: Can you give me an example doing it this way?

Comment: Start here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html. HTTP is sort of involved protocol. You probably don't want doing it by hand the first time around.