# Java: ServletOuputStream content length

Tags: java, servlets, download

For downloading a file, i use the following methods of HttpServletResponse

```
resp.setContentType("application/force-download");
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment;filename=" + "\"" + name + "\"");
```

There is also a method to set the content length of the response. What are the advantages of this method? When should I use this method?

Comment: It's automatically set for you, unless you're using HTTP 1.0 or a non-default streaming mode. Don't worry abut it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the header **Content-Length**, this specifies the length of the response in bytes.

An advantage would be to make the receptor aware of the total size of the response and be able to show a progress bar in the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

> It means the exact byte length of the HTTP body. Generally it is used for HTTP 1.1 so that the receiving party knows when the current response/request has finished, so the connection can be reused for another request. Alternatively, content-length can be omitted and a chunked encoding can be used, or if both are missing, then at the end of the response the connection must be closed.

Taken from [What's the "Content-Length" field in HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773396/whats-the-content-length-field-in-http-header).