# Openssl iOS buffer limit

Tags: ios, io, openssl

I'm using openssl in my iOS application, and it works fines until i sent too big message (100kb) from server to client  (iOS app).

the problem is the ssl_read() method have a limit buffer size as 16384 bytes, so if the server send a message big than 16384 bytes, the reset of the message it will be ignored.

my question is how i can change this limit (increase this limit) ?

Comment: Do note that you might in any case be better served by using Apple's APIs instead of OpenSSL; if you use the latter, you need to keep it up to date, and you'll want to ship it in your application bundle.  For ordinary HTTPS, you can do most things with Core Foundation and/or Foundation.  For more complex tasks, look at Secure Transport and/or Common Crypto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You cannot change the limit.  You have to read a chunk of data, save it in a buffer, read another chunk, append it to that buffer, and so on until you've received the entire message.

**Longer answer:**

The maximum record size is 16384 (2^14) because it's defined that way by the standard.  For example, for TLS 1.2, that is [rfc5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246).

> The record layer fragments information blocks into TLSPlaintext
> records carrying data in chunks of 2^14 bytes or less.  Client
> message boundaries are not preserved in the record layer (i.e.,
> multiple client messages of the same ContentType MAY be coalesced
> into a single TLSPlaintext record, or a single message MAY be
> fragmented across several records).

The spec makes it quite clear that the length has a fixed size:

> The length MUST NOT exceed 2^14.

Your transmitter should not be constructing SSL records larger than that.  It should be fragmenting the message over multiple SSL records.

An SSL record is analogous to an IP packet.  The maximum amount of data you can actually put inside an IP packet is a little less than your [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit), which is commonly 1500 bytes.  So how does TCP work, which allows you to send arbitrary-length messages?  Well, it works by sending your message in chunks, 1500 bytes at a time until you've received your entire message.

How does TCP know when you've received your whole message?  It doesn't.  It has no idea.  That's why TCP is called a stream protocol.  It's just streaming bytes to your app.  Your app must know when it has received a message.  In the case of HTTP, you'd know because the client sends a [Content-Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773396/whats-the-content-length-field-in-http-header) header that tells the server how many bytes to expect.

Same with `ssl_read`.  You read a chunk of data at a time until your app has determined when you've read an entire message.  You accumulate these chunks in a larger buffer that your application manages.