# How to send string via http request in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multipartform-data

I am trying to setup a upload for a string data by ONLY using javascript `formdata` without an actual form.

I have something like this.

```
var string = JSON.stringify(jsonfile);

var formdata = new FormData();

var stringBlob = new Blob([string]);
formdata.append('file', stringBlob);
```

The upload part:

```
  $http.post(‘myurl/upload’, formdata, {
         'headers' : {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data' }})
```

The request payload for `formdata`

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryarzhWTykl2Z6sSZ1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="stringBlob"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
------WebKitFormBoundaryarzhWTykl2Z6sSZ1--
```

For some reason, it doesn’t work. It comes with 200 OK response on the request but I think it never does the upload. Can someone help me about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe content size is also required.

Comment: try to append your text values to form data

Comment: @archer could you please explain more detail?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773396/whats-the-content-length-field-in-http-header