# Correct value of content-length for HTTP text payloads

Tags: http, http-headers, content-length, http-content-length

I am currently developing a HTTP server application, and I am struggling with the size of body payloads.

According to the spec (and also [What's the “Content-Length” field in HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773396/whats-the-content-length-field-in-http-header)), the HTTP header `Content-Length` contains the actual number of bytes of the whole body payload.

Now, say I'm firing this:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --request POST --data 'test' http://localhost:5555/
```

my server will receive a `Content-Length` header which contains the value `4`. Since I am sending a string, and the string including null-byte will have 5 bytes, I would expect the `Content-Length` to be `5`, and the request body to contain the null-byte as well.

Is my assumption wrong? Or is this some kind of curl issue? I tried with another tool (Paw on Mac), which actually has the option of sending text payloads, with the same result.

Comment: The string that you're sending here doesn't contain a null byte, so 4 is the correct length.

Comment: Okay so you mean both those tools send only 4 bytes although I am giving them a string which is having 5 bytes in total? I mean thats the definition of string (that it includes a nullbyte beyond the character count).
So is this to be expected/normal that clients will **not** send a nullbyte when they are (knowingly) sending string data?

Comment: No, that's not the definition of "String". How string lengths are handled (end-of-string marker vs length counter) depends on the programming language/environment.