# What is the CONTENT_LENGTH varaible of a CGI?

Tags: bash, http, cgi

[RFC 3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.2) defines the CONTENT_LENGTH in this way:

> The CONTENT_LENGTH variable contains the size of the message-body
> attached to the request, if any, in decimal number of octets.  If no
> data is attached, then NULL (or unset).
>
> ```
> CONTENT_LENGTH = "" | 1*digit
> ```
>
> The server MUST set this meta-variable if and only if the request is
> accompanied by a message-body entity.  The CONTENT_LENGTH value must
> reflect the length of the message-body after the server has removed
> any transfer-codings or content-codings.

I am not sure which size this is.

Is it the size of the data the clients wants to send, which means the value of the HTTP request header "Content-Length"?

Or is it the size of the data the HTTP server read from the request before the data is send to the CGI?

I ask because I am not sure who is responsible to check, that the amount of data, the client wants to send matches the amount of data actually arrived. Is the HTTP server responsible to check that the size matches the value in the request header, or is the CGI responsible to count the bytes, which arrive on STDIN? And if so how gets the CGI the value of the request header?

Right now I do this in my CGI:

```
cat > $TMP/upload.csv
size=$(stat -c %s "$TMP/upload.csv")
if [ "$CONTENT_LENGTH" != "$size" ]; then
  echo "Size missmatch"
  return -1
fi
```

But is it the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP `Content-Length` already discussed here [What's the "Content-Length" field in HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2773396/7939871) is defining the length of the body part only for the `HTTP`'s protocol scope.

If your body is transmitted binary, `the Content-Length` is the same as the data length within the `HTTP` request.

When your body is 7-bit ASCII encoded, the `Content-Length` is usually higher than the actual data.

To summarize: `Content-Length` need be computed before transmitting the body of the `HTTP` request.

In your case, you may not compare the `Content-Length` with the file length. These are disconnected values.

Your file may be transmitted with multiple `HTTP` requests and answers with partial content, and each `HTTP` request and answers will get its own `Content-Length`.

If your intent is to do integrity check ; then use HTTPS for transmission integrity check, or use check-sums, or other protocols like `rsync` with built-in integrity check.

Comment: I do the post with `application/octet-stream` without encoding.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You talk about the HTTP header `Content-Length`. I talk about the CGI variable `CONTENT_LENGTH`.

Comment: Well I could relieve the statement that `Content-Length` is disconnected from File length. Some downloaders manages partial download by looking at the file length and requesting the remaining at computed offset. Anyway comparing size with `Content-Lengh` is a very weak check, to continue a partial transmission. A more elaborate integrity check is still better.

Comment: @ceving the `CGI` variable `CONTENT_LENGTH` is just the copy of the `Content-Length: <number>` `HTTP` header.

Comment: Really? I gave some arguments in my question, that this might be wrong.