# Angular 8 - overwrite content-length

Tags: c#, angular, http-headers

I am trying to send a large string to c# controller. controller signature looks like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] string longString)
```

I am getting longString as null. I am doing the same in Postman and see that if turn off the default Content-Length header which says: "calculated when request is sent" and add the same header with a value that equal the length of the string + 8 the back end gets correct value as it does when default Content-Length header is on. My POST request from Angular has everything the same except the value of Content-Length header. It is equal the length of the string + 6. So, I am trying to change Content-Length header value to the one that works in Postman like this:

```
    headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json;');
    headers.set('Content-Length', '140317');
```

But Network shows that the above change is not taking a place.

Any idea how get it work?

Thanks

Comment: please try this if you can make it 
`headers.set('Content-Length', 1*(string.length));`
  check reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/2773465/6923146

Comment: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[]'

Comment: `headers.set('Content-Length', (1*(string.length)).toString());`

Comment: Just curios, how is it different from headers.set('Content-Length', '140317');

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: I think the problem is that HttpHeaders is immutable. You need to use a decorator pattern by chaining the calls: headers = new HttpHeaders().set(...).append(...).append(...)